# AWS Codepipeline python submodule manual build works pipeline auto trigger giving error GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

Triggering manual build works, but codepipeline based builds are giving the GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM error

fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /codebuild)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set)

Tried setting up env variables but not working.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n1pc.png)Setting pipeline source step to below(full clone instead of CodePipeline default) worked,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Mwmt.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).